# MySQL 1422, explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I understand that I cannot do a transaction inside a trigger, but I CAN inside a procedure. And I should be able to call a procedure from a trigger. Which is exactly what I'm doing.

TABLE A has an "after update trigger".
I only want to call the procedure if one of two columns has been changed.

TABLE A TRIGGER:

```
IF (
    NEW.colA != OLD.colA
OR
    NEW.colB != OLD.colB
) THEN
    call setBonuses( NEW.colA, NEW.colB );
END IF
```

The setBonuses SP effects TABLE B by doing some calculations using TABLE_A.colA,TABLE_A.colB (I don't think it's relevant, but TABLE B does have an "after update trigger", but it has a conditional to only do its update if fields NOT effected by the below procedure are changed, so it does 'nothing' when the bonus field is updated.)

THE STORED PROCEDURE:

```
begin

    IF A > B THEN
        SET n = A;
        ...
    ELSEIF A < B THEN
        SET n = B;
        ...
    END IF;

    start transaction;

    -- Bonuses
    UPDATE TABLE_B
    SET bonus = 0
    WHERE... ;

    UPDATE TABLE_B
    SET bonus = bonus + n
    WHERE...;

    UPDATE TABLE_B
    SET bonus = bonus + n
    WHERE...;

    UPDATE TABLE_B
    SET bonus = bonus + n
    WHERE...;

    UPDATE TABLE_B
    SET bonus = bonus + n
    WHERE...;

    UPDATE TABLE_B
    SET bonus = bonus + n
    WHERE...;

commit;
end
```

The SP works fine if called directly by the application, however, I don't want to have to explicitly call it as a chain in some event, I really just need it to do its calcs and  update TABLE B - whenever someone changed TABLE A (colA or colB).

Any reason why this isn't possible.

Comment: You should really recreate your stored procedure to single UPDATE which is with implicit transaction itself. It looks like it is possible to do with UPDATE + Subquery.

Comment: well there are 5 different complicated criteria that determine bonuses, it cannot be expressed in one statement.